# How many ways we can load $100$ indistinguishable boxes into $3$ cars A,B,C,if every car can be loaded with $20$ to $40$ boxes?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, balls-in-bins

I am trying to solve some exercises. Those exercises have to do with P(n,r) and C(n,r).There are

**exercise 1**: How many ways we can load $100$ **indistinguishable boxes** into $3$ cars A,B,C,if every car can be loaded with $20$ to $40$ boxes?

How I solve it: It says same boxes, so  step 1 I know that it is $C(n,r)$.  We know that $n=100$, we know that $r=3$.

We can say that we can split into categories for **A**,suppose we use $40$ to load so **n=100** and $r=100-40=60$, so $r=60$.   $C(100,60)$

With the same way I can do the B, and I have for **B** the  $C(60,20)$.

As a result the last **C**, $60-40$ car can be $C(20,0)$.

***formula for A :*** I have $$C(n,r)= \frac{n!}{r!(n−r)!} = \frac{60!}{100!(100-60)!}= \frac{60!}{100!40!} =$$
Something doesn't go well.

***formula for B :*** $\dfrac{60!}{60!(60!-40!)}$, which is wrong and this one.

***formula for C :*** $\dfrac{20!}{20!(20!-0!)}=1$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133424/discussion-on-question-by-yun-kon-how-many-ways-we-can-load-100-indistinguisha).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boxes $A,B,C$ means labeled boxes, so the problem boils down to putting indistinguishable balls into distinguishable boxes, and the tool to use is [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))

We simplify the problem in two steps so that we can apply the *basic* stars and bars formula

- We first place $20$ balls in each box so the problem now reduces to placing  $40$ balls in the three boxes with a (now) upper limit of $20$ per box
- The integer equation is $x_1 + x_2 +x_3 = 40,\; 0\leq{x_i}\leq 20$
- The second simplification is a change of variable, We write $(20-y_1) + (20-y_2) + (20-y_3) = 40,$ which gives $y_1+y_2+y_3 = 20, y_i \geq 0$

Now we can use the basic stars and bars formula, to get $\binom{20+3-1}{3-1} $